# Alignment of the component in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am new in React and I am trying to align the component at a particular place but I am not able to do so.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Typography, Container, Grid, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import useStyles from "./styles";

function Home() {
  const classes = useStyles;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item sm={6} xs={12}>
          <Typography variant="h3" color="textPrimary" gutterBottom>
            Hello, there.
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="h5" paragraph>
            I need to put this in the centre of the shaded region.
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <div>
        <Grid item sm={3} xs={6}>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" disableElevation>
            download
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am using `useStyles` Hooks to do so.

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    top: "50%"
  }
}));

export default useStyles;
```

But it is not working, is there a way to solve this?

[image]

Comment: The shaded region is 60% of the screen

Comment: Do you need to center **everything** (title, text & button) or just the text?

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals Yes I need to

Comment: I bundled everything in root class and trying to have  top:"50%", but it is not working

Comment: As per https://material-ui.com/api/grid/, you can add *alignContent* and *alignItems* properties to achieve what you want to do. You'll have to  do differently for the button though since you put it in a different `div`.

Comment: It isn't working for me, I am using `<Grid item sm={6} xs={12} alignContent="center">`

Comment: Woops, I mistook `alignContent` with `justifyContent`. Try with the latter.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you want to achieve, but I think [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) article about flex layout will help you understand how to position elements.

and try the following maybe it's what you want:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Typography, Container, Grid, Button } from "@material-ui/core";

function Home() {

  return (
   <Grid container style={{
                           justifyContent: "center"
                            }}>
      <Grid container style={{
                              backgraoundColor: "blue",
                              maxWidth: "700px",
                              alignItems: "center",
                              justifyContent: "center"
                            }}>
          <Typography variant="h3" color="textPrimary" gutterBottom>
            Hello, there.
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="h5" paragraph>
            I need to put this in the centre of the shaded region.
          </Typography>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" disableElevation>
           download
          </Button>
     </Grid>
  </Grid>
 );
}
```

Comment: Actually, I need to put that button, text n title in the center of the shaded region. and using alignItems , it is aligning then to the center of the page, not to the center of the shaded region.

Comment: did you try the above code it's center every thing inside container, still not clear, do you want to center texts and button vertically and horizontally inside the shaded region, and then center the shaded region horizontally

Comment: Yes I tried your code, it is aligning it to the center of page not to the center of that particular region. And what I want is to align everything in the middle of that shaded region.

Comment: I have updated my answer, by adding another container "Main container" and the second container "shaded", hope this will help, I also suggest to read the article if you understand flex layout, then you will be able to do what ever you want

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your content into a div and apply following styles to it

```
shaded_region{
display:flex,
justify-content:"center",
}
```